# Breadcrumb trail wordpress custom users

Tags: php, wordpress

I have currently got an online directory created within wordpress but I am experiencing some issues with declaring the username for non authors.

```
} elseif ( is_author() || is_user_member_of_blog() ) {
    global $author;
    $userdata = get_userdata($author);
    echo $before . sprintf($text['author'], $userdata->display_name) . $after;

}
```

This piece of codes echos out the "username" but only for administrators and no one else. I got users as subscribers, so is there anyway to define the role?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a username of the currently logged in user, 
you can nick this example from the codex.

From the horses mouth: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo

```
<?php 

  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();

  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
  echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
  echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
  echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";

?>
```

If if misunderstood the question, feel free to elaborate.